# Can anyone help me with this? getting this exception

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**Expected a value of type '`List<Widget>`', but got one of type '`List<dynamic>'`**

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually quite simple.
The list you should specify should be a list of widgets, for example List[Container(color: Colors.red), Container(color: Colors.blue,), ...]. What you specify is a dynamic list, so not a list of widgets. An error solution could be that instead of List you make List in your list and add widgets to it.

Answer (score 0):

Did You try to specify an generic type to the list?
for example:

**instead:**

```
final list = [Container(...), Container(...), ...];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: list,
    );
}
```

**making something like:**

```
final list = <Widget>[Container(...), Container(...), ...];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: list,
    );
}
```

**you can also make something like (using the spread operator):**

```dart
final list = <Widget>[Container(...), Container(...), ...];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: [...list],
    );
}
```

Sorry. I tried to be as generic as possible. If you don't feel helped, to be more assertive, would be interesting some code snippet showing exactly what you doing.

What result did you expect to produce?